# implementation error when i try to put 2

Tags: ios, implementation

This is my implementation line

```
@implementation ViewController
```

however I want to add `pickerViewController` but even though I do

```
@implementation ViewController, pickerViewController I can't do it
```

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, and you want two implementation directives on a single .m file, then you can't just comma separate the implementations. Each @implementation requires you to explicitly add @end.

```
@implementation ViewController
    // code here
@end

@implementation pickerViewController
    // other code here
@end
```